# Importing moviepy editor gives typeerror

Tags: python, moviepy

When I try to import the moviepy packagage I get the following type error.

```
import moviepy.editor as mpy
```

Output:

```
File ~\Miniconda3\envs\vids\lib\site-packages\moviepy\editor.py:24 in <module>
 import imageio

File ~\Miniconda3\envs\vids\lib\site-packages\imageio\__init__.py:24 in <module>
 from .core import FormatManager, RETURN_BYTES

File ~\Miniconda3\envs\vids\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\__init__.py:16 in <module>
 from .format import Format, FormatManager

File ~\Miniconda3\envs\vids\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\format.py:40 in <module>
 from ..config import known_plugins, known_extensions, PluginConfig, FileExtension

File ~\Miniconda3\envs\vids\lib\site-packages\imageio\config\__init__.py:7 in <module>
 from .plugins import known_plugins, PluginConfig

File ~\Miniconda3\envs\vids\lib\site-packages\imageio\config\plugins.py:3 in <module>
 from ..core.legacy_plugin_wrapper import LegacyPlugin

File ~\Miniconda3\envs\vids\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\legacy_plugin_wrapper.py:5 in <module>
 from .v3_plugin_api import PluginV3, ImageProperties

File ~\Miniconda3\envs\vids\lib\site-packages\imageio\core\v3_plugin_api.py:2 in <module>
 from ..typing import ArrayLike

File ~\Miniconda3\envs\vids\lib\site-packages\imageio\typing.py:6 in <module>
 from numpy.typing import ArrayLike

File ~\Miniconda3\envs\vids\lib\site-packages\numpy\typing\__init__.py:329 in <module>
 from ._dtype_like import (

File ~\Miniconda3\envs\vids\lib\site-packages\numpy\typing\_dtype_like.py:16 in <module>
 from ._generic_alias import _DType as DType

File ~\Miniconda3\envs\vids\lib\site-packages\numpy\typing\_generic_alias.py:211 in <module>
 _DType = np.dtype[ScalarType]

TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

I am running python v3.9 and moviepy v1.03, although I have tested v1.01 and gotten the same error. How do I import this package successfully?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I think this is a great first question! Generally when I see this error (which is rare) it is due to conflicting library versions (ie., `imageio`, `numpy`, `moviepy` are not getting along). Are you using a virtual environment to install your packages? You can see from the traceback that the problem is `imageio` importing `numpy`, which potentially means that `numpy` is different from what `imageio` is expecting. Consider downgrading your `numpy` version.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed this problem by deleting my virtual environment and creating it again. This time I installed numpy first in conda before installing moviepy.